# Grading system using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

1. In the database, some courses value are NULL, and I don't want to print courses that hava a NULL value.
   I don't know how I can achieve this in php or mysql. I need something like so:

   `if(course1!=NULL || course2!=NULL || course3!=NULL || course4!=NULL){
   // echo course1; echo course2; echo course3; echo course4; }`

The database looks like this:

[image: The database]

And the output so far look like this:
[image]

2. A remark() function which check whether the course is A, B, C, D, E, or F is not working properly.
   I want the remark() function to output either Excellent, Credit, Pass, or fail base on the grade.

   Follows is the code:

   ```
   function remark(){

   global $mathematics, $physics, $chemistry, $lang;

   if($mathematics=='A' || $physics=='A' || $chemistry=='A' || $lang=='A'){
       $remark = "Excellent";
   }

   elseif($mathematics=='B' || $physics=='B' || $chemistry=='B' || $lang=='B' || $mathematics=='C' || $physics=='C' || $chemistry=='C' || $lang=='C'){
   $remark = "Credit";
   }
   elseif($mathematics=='D' || $physics=='D' || $chemistry=='D' ||         $lang=='D' || $mathematics=='E' || $physics=='E' || $chemistry=='E' || $lang=='E'){
       $remark = "Pass";
   }
       else{
       $remark = "Fail";
   }
   return $remark;
   }
   if(isset($_POST['student_id']) && !empty($_POST['student_id'])){$student_id = $_POST['student_id'];

          $check = "SELECT * FROM sample1 WHERE student_id='$student_id'";
          $check_query = mysqli_query($connection, $check);
          if(mysqli_num_rows($check_query)>0){

    while($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_query)){

           $mathematics = $query_row['mathematics'];
           $physics = $query_row['physics'];
           $chemistry = $query_row['chm'];
           $lang = $query_row['lang'];

   echo "<table border=1 width=50%>
           <tr> <td>Name: ".$query_row['name']."  </td> 
               <td>Student Id: ".$query_row['student_id']."</td>
               <td>Level: ".$query_row['level']."</td>
           </tr>
           <tr> 
               <th> Course </th>
               <th> Grade </th> 
               <th> Remark </th>  
           </tr>

           <tr> <td>Mathematics </td> <td>".$mathematics." </td></td> <td>".remark()." </td></tr>
           <tr> <td>Physics </td> <td>".$physics."</td> </td><td>".remark()." </td></tr>
           <tr> <td>Chemistry </td> <td>".$chemistry."</td> </td><td>".remark()." </td></tr>
           <tr> <td>Language </td> <td>".$lang."</td> </td><td>".remark()." </td></tr>

       </table>";
                     }
                   }
                   else{echo "Record not found";}
                   }
   ```

Comment: Remember your title is how and why people click on your question. A question with a bad title is less likely to get answered.

Comment: But on first sight it looks like you don't have an optimal database-structure. The courses should be in another table, as the results per student.

Comment: Do you want to return 'Excellent' , 'Fail' etc. as soon as one of the grades reach the require or should all meet the requirements. Because right now if a Student receives and A in physics and B in mathematics the function will just return 'Excellent'

Comment: ...and having `$mathematics, $physics, $chemistry, $lang` is a bad idea. Pass them to the function as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the MYSQL not null values, you use this:

`SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE course1 IS NOT NULL`

So, IS NOT NULL will give you queries where that column (course1) is not null. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) more info.

And for PHP, your `remark()` function has a wrong approach. I will give you one that is correct for your purpouse.

```
function remark($course){

    switch($course) {

        case 'A':
            return 'Excellent';
        break;

        case 'B':
        case 'C':
            return 'Credit';
        break;

        case 'D':
        case 'E':
            return 'Pass';
        break;

        default:
            return 'Fail';
        break;

    }

}
```

So in your HTML table you do this for each course:

```
while ($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_query)) {

    $mathematics = $query_row['mathematics'];
    $physics     = $query_row['physics'];
    $chemistry   = $query_row['chm'];
    $lang        = $query_row['lang'];

    echo "<table border=1 width=50%>
        <tr> <td>Name: " . $query_row['name'] . "  </td>
            <td>Student Id: " . $query_row['student_id'] . "</td>
            <td>Level: " . $query_row['level'] . "</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> Course </th>
            <th> Grade </th>
            <th> Remark </th>
        </tr>"

        if(!is_null($mathematics)) echo "<tr> <td>Mathematics </td> <td>" . $mathematics . " </td></td> <td>" . remark($mathematics) . " </td></tr>";
        if(!is_null($physics)) echo "<tr> <td>Physics </td> <td>" . $physics . "</td> </td><td>" . remark($physics) . " </td></tr>";
        if(!is_null($chemistry)) echo "<tr> <td>Chemistry </td> <td>" . $chemistry . "</td> </td><td>" . remark($chemistry) . " </td></tr>";
        if(!is_null($lang)) echo "<tr> <td>Language </td> <td>" . $lang . "</td> </td><td>" . remark($lang) . " </td></tr>";

    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: This (first issue) will not return the student at all. That's not what he/she wants to achieve.

Comment: You are right, I understood what was he asking, he means an `IF` to check in the `WHILE` to see if is not null (if it was coursed)

Comment: @P0lT10n, the solution worked flawlessly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer for the first issue extending the answer of @P0IT10n (?):

```
 <?php
     if(!is_null($mathematics)) { 
 ?>
        <tr> <td>Mathematics </td> <td>".$mathematics." </td></td> <td>".remark($mathematics)." </td></tr>
 <?php
     }
 ?>
 // repeat for other courses
```

**BUT**
rethink your database structure.
Once you have another course you're f***...
Courses should have their own table, results another one.
Read about database normalisation!

**EDIT**
Another extension:
It would be even easier if you'd have an array like this:

```
$remarks = array('A'=>'Excellent', 'B'=>'Good',...);
```

then you need no extra function with a switch, all you need to do is:

```
echo $remarks[$mathematics]; // -> Excellent
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I like the array solution